# My user controls don't appear in tool box

Tags: c#, controls

i have program with some user controls but when i build solutions the user controls don't appear on tool box, for test i made another user control and after re build it appeared on tool box !  this is one of my user controls:

```
 using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AMIgo
{
  /// <summary>A UserControl used to display and interact with the active calls.</summary>
  /// <remarks>This display reflect the content of the <see cref="AMI_Client.AstCallsList"/> which contains the current active calls.
  /// The ListViewCalls display allows to show the items in differents layouts, in a similar way than the windows file explorer.
  /// <para>A menu allows to select to display Inbound( show in Red (default), Outbound (shown in blue) and internal (shown in gray) calls.</para>
  /// <para>Properties allows to set the font and colors of the ListView and ListItems</para>
  /// <para>Drag / Drop: You can drag an active call and drop it onto an extension in the <see cref="ListViewLines"/> display to Transfer a 
  /// caller to an extension. You can drag and drop an active call to the display toolbar drop target to Transfer the active channel to the 
  /// selected destination, to park the call or to hang it up. You can also drag an active channel to the <see cref="AMIgoDropTarget"/> form to Transfer a call to the selected destination. 
  /// (Extension, queue, conference, etc)</para>
  /// <para> Context Menu: Right click on an item to open a Context menu.</para>
  /// <seealso cref="AstCall"/><seealso cref="AMI_Client.NewCallEvent"/></remarks>
  [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(AMIgo.ListViewCalls), "Resources.Control_ListView.bmp")]
  public partial class ListViewCalls : AMIgoControl
  {
    /// <summary>Gets or sets a value indicating whether the intermediary agents channels are displayed.</summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> to show Agents channels otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool ShowAgentsChannels { get; set; }
    private bool _show_outbound_calls;
    /// <summary>Gets or sets a value indicating whether the outbound calls are displayed.</summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> to show outbound calls, otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool ShowOutboundCalls 
    {
      get { return (_show_outbound_calls); } 
      set 
      {
        _show_outbound_calls = value;
        outboundToolStripMenuItem.Checked = _show_outbound_calls;
      }
    }
    private bool _show_internal_calls;
.
.
.
.
.
```

and this is AMIgoControl file...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AMIgo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// This is the base control from which inherit most of the AMIgo controls
  /// </summary>
  [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  public class AMIgoControl : UserControl
  {
    /// <summary>true after this control has been initialized. </summary>
    public bool _InitDone;
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the AMI_Client instance. The AMI_Client component will set this on startup if left blank.</summary>
    public virtual AMIgo.AMI_Client AMI_ClientInstance { get; set; }
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AMIgoControl"/> class.</summary>
    public AMIgoControl() { }
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AMIgoControl"/> class. </summary>
    /// <param name="AMI_ClientInstance">The AMI_Client instance.</param>
    public AMIgoControl(AMIgo.AMI_Client AMI_ClientInstance)
    {
      this.AMI_ClientInstance = AMI_ClientInstance;
    }
    /// <summary>Finds a Control recursively. Note finds the first match and exits</summary>
    /// <param name="Container">The container to search for the given control type.
    /// Remember all controls (Panel, GroupBox, Form, etc are all containers for controls
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="TypeName">Name of the type of control to look for</param>
    /// <returns>The control object if found or null</returns>
    /// 
    public Control FindControlRecursive(Control Container, string TypeName)
    {
      if (Container.GetType().Name == TypeName)
        return Container;

      foreach (Control ctrl in Container.Controls)
      {
        Control foundCtrl = FindControlRecursive(ctrl, TypeName);
        if (foundCtrl != null)
          return foundCtrl;
      }
      return null;
    }

  } //UserControl
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the starters: Toolbox in VS applies context filters so, you won't see the user controls unless you have a designer opened and active in the document well.  If you have tried this and still don't see the controls - would you be able to post a screenshot for better understanding?  Also, mention the version of VS you are using - I just tried creating a sample UC on VS12 and it works just as expected.  Perhaps, you might want to do that test too and post the update with result.

update: by the way, you might want to remove that ToolboxItem(false) attribute on AMIgo class.

Comment: Oh! by the way, you might want to remove that "ToolboxItem(false)" attribute on AMIgo class.

Comment: I made this changes:    //[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
  //[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]    and this is ok now....  thanks alot

Comment: Did it work?  In case if you wanted to Show ListViewCalls in the toolbox but hide the base control AMIgoControl, apply the two attributes to ListViewCalls and set them to true:
  [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]